# How can I insert or update a js-timestamp component after the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sails.js

Background: I'm using the SailsJS framework to display the timestamp of when a data model was updated. The framework comes from something they call 'parasails', which uses Vue.js. It provides the `<js-timestamp :at="1573487792252">` component to display a message like "a few seconds ago" which automatically updates as time passes. As time passes by, the "time since" message will dynamically update so it might say something like "5 minutes ago." Simultaneous to this, the underlying model in my project can be updated and that update gets passed to the browser with a WebSocket. When that happens, I want to update the `<js-timestamp>` to reflect the new reference timestamp.

Problem: When the HTML first loads, parasails replaces the `<js-timestamp>` element with a `<span parasails-component="js-timestamp">` which contains the literal "time since" message and not the integer timestamp. Presumably, parasails stores that integer in a JavaScript variable. I have tried using JQuery to insert a new `<js-timestamp>` but parasails does not catch on. The tag remains in the DOM, but it doesn't get updated with a "time since" message. I can see from the [source code](https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/02afde47196e5dd15e53d4f0efcd5a24) of the `js-timestamp` component that it uses the `moment(this.at).fromNow()` to get the "time since" message when the timestamp is less than 24 hours old, but if I use that and replace the text manually, it no longer updates on its own as time passes.

Question: What is the proper way to update the timestamp so that parasails (or Vue.js or whatever) continues to update the message as time passes?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I can just define a variable in the JavaScript associated with the page and set the `js-timestamp :at` attribute to the variable name instead of an integer literal. Then when the variable updates, so does the page.

Instead of this:

```
<js-timestamp :at="1573487792252">
```

I now use this:

```
<js-timestamp :at="model.updatedAt">
```